# Smtp client - from and to not send

Tags: c++, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have an smtp client build in c++ where I can send emails to my testing mailtrap account.
The headers are send and the email is arriving just fine.

**My problem is, that the field which indicates from/to is empty - as displayed in the screenshot**

[image]

I'm sending the header with

```
write_command("MAIL FROM: <foo@bar.de>");
write_command("RCPT TO: <foo@bar.de>");
```

I made a gist with my full code of the Smtp client

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7bb13de7f044bcb5d07d0e6a9d991ea9

I'm calling it from my `main()` function

with

```
 Smtp smtp_client = Smtp();
 smtp_client.new_connection("smtp.mailtrap.io", 25);
 smtp_client.auth_login("username", "password");
 smtp_client.sendmail();
 smtp_client.close_connection();
```

thanks for tacking a look

Comment: I think I made it. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to make the fields appear, editing your `sendmail` function a bit:

```
void sendmail()
{
    write_command("MAIL FROM: <foo@bar.de>");
    write_command("RCPT TO: <foo@bar.de>");

    write_command("DATA");

    std::string data;
    data.append("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n");
    data.append("From: <foo@bar.de>\r\n");
    data.append("To: <foo@bar.de>\r\n");
    data.append("Subject: Welcome\r\n");
    data.append("Date: Fri, 29 Dec 2017 09:30:00 -0400\r\n");
    data.append("\r\n"); //this seems to matter
    data.append("This is a test");
    data.append("\r\n.");
    write_command(data);

    write_command("QUIT");
}
```

I put the whole DATA in a string and sent it in a single write.

What (apparently) matters:

1. don't start the data section with an empty line;
2. add an empty line before the message text.

I also edited your `write_command`, it doesn't relate to your issue but I suggest you don't copy the string to a buffer but directly use the string instead:

```
    //char command_buffer[255];
    //strcpy(command_buffer, command.c_str());
    //n = write(sockfd,command_buffer,strlen(command_buffer));
    n = write(sockfd,command.c_str(),command.length());
```

Comment: I investigated further, and I think it is an intentional limitation for free accounts. Whenever you enter the demo inbox, an xhr downloads messages in json format, and each object has many fields left empty, notably: `from_email`, `from_name`, `to_email`, `to_name` ... basically, all you get for free is `text_body` and few other information.

Comment: I thought the same at first - but when I do the same thing with telnet- those fields are filled. so I guess I missed something

Comment: thanks a lot for all the effort you put in here-  this really helped me